# How can I fix maven hang during gwt-maven-plugin:compile?

Tags: gwt-maven-plugin

mvn clean install results in the following which stalls until I kill the process.  This only happens as a part of a much larger build on a bamboo server.  When I build locally the build doesn't stall.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) @ alerts ---
[WARNING] Don't declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts
[INFO] Compiling module com....alerts.Alerter
```

- What can I do to gain better insight into the hang?
- What are the likely causes of the hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a problem with memory.  If you are bounded by x86 limits (as I am in this case) then you can use gwt.localWorker to reduce memory footprint.  Fewer workers translates to less parallel needs and a longer build. Increasing memory may prevent the problem.  Increasing the logLevel may expose the nature of the stall.

The following got me past my stall.

```
<gwt.compiler.localWorkers>1</gwt.compiler.localWorkers>
<gwt.logLevel>TRACE</gwt.logLevel>
<gwt.extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=target</gwt.extraJvmArgs>
```

**Suggestions For Improving Rep Ability**
 - Compare environment settings between build server and local for better ability to rep.  JAVA_OPTS and MAVEN_OPTS may import
 - Ensure you use identical build commands in both contexts
 - try running with -pl :module-artifact-name on build server to reduce time to failure
 - mvn -X will provide some additional